# How to change the title of 'Firefox Developer Edition' in the menubar of OS X?

Tags: firefox

Is it possible to change the title of 'Firefox Developer Edition' in the menubar of OS X (too long)?

[image]

There is [the issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1101475) in Mozilla's Bugzilla but it's few years old, seems like nobody is going to change it soon.

Comment: You're right, it seems nobody will. If already reported as a bug and without a solution or workaround, I don't know what answer were you expecting here?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia, I'm expecting to find out if there is a way to just use OS X resources to change a title of an app? I tried Info.plst inside the app bundle but it didn't help.